# Open app store from code

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

In some free apps there is a button for buy pro version of app that if you touch it app store  app will open how can i do that from code ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The iPhone/iPad will automatically recognize an AppStore URL if you just:

```
- (IBAction)OpenAppInAppStore {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wolframalpha/id334989259?mt=8"]];

}
```

or if you open any URL that has "`itms://`" and only on the device

Comment: Nice, but this method at first open a iTunes app. Then iTunes open a App Store. So, is too slow. Can we open at once a App Store?

Answer (score 7):

1. Launch iTunes on your computer.
2. Search for the item you want to link to.
3. Right-click or control-click on the item's name in iTunes, then choose "Copy iTunes Store URL" from the pop-up menu.
4. Open the <strike>modified</strike> URL using an NSURL object and the -[UIApplication openURL] method.

Read [Technical Q&A QA1629](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1629.html). They also offer a method how you can add your iTunes Affiliate link without redirecting from your app to safari to the appstore

Comment: In Address that you offer here are 3 method for add iTunes Affiliate link without redirecting from your app to safari to the appstore but i don't know how to use them mean at first which method should i call?

Comment: Ok, @Matthias Bauch, but how to get which is the App Store (which country) - I need to open App Store for installation of 3rd party app. But the App store can be either Italy, either UK. How to get which URL to use?

Answer (score 1):

Use the function openURL from UIApplication with the iTunes URL link of your App.